# Query Excel using ADO from VB.NET when a column name is a number

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, ado

I am using VB.NET to query via SQL an Excel spreadsheet using ADO.

The general way is like this:

```
SELECT [firstname], [secondname] FROM [Sheet1$]
```

Which works perfectly
However, one of the headings is called 3, so I want to do:

```
SELECT [firstname], [secondname], [3] FROM [Sheet1$]
```

However, this does not work.
I know I can use `*` to get all columns, but later on I want to use (using dataReader):

`dr("3")` 
which won't work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using (or implying) `HDR=YES` in the connection string, an illegal column name will be replaced with the column's ordinal position appended with the letter `F`.

For example, if your column named `3` is the fifth column in the Excel Range then its name will be considered to be `F5`.

Comment: thanks, this works. I just used F and the number of the column and it worked perfectly. Yes I am using `HDR=YES`.